# UpdatePanel Breaks JQuery Script on datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, datalist

I have an update panel and inside the update panel I have a datalist.

On the datalist I have multi div

```
<div class="prod_details_tab">
    <div class="prod_details_sell">
        <a href="Handler.ashx?action=addToBasket&productID=4" onclick="return false;">
            <img src="images/cart.gif" alt='<%#String.Format("{0}", Eval("k_name1")) %>'
                width="16" height="16" id='<%#String.Format("{0}", Eval("k_name1")) %>'
                class="left_IB" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I write a jQuery code that when a person click on cart.gif pic run the jQuery

```
 $(".prod_details_sell a img").click(function () {
        //some code is here
});
```

On the first page of datalist jquery run good and all thing is ok.

But on the second page when I click on `cart.gif` pic jQuery does not run.

Please help me to fix it

Thanks

Edit: I write next button and prev button click in here

```
   protected void cmdNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        // Set viewstate variable to the previous page
        CurrentPage += 1;

        PagedDataSource pagedDS = new PagedDataSource();
        pagedDS.DataSource = ((DataTable)Cache["DataTable-cach"]).DefaultView;// cacheItem.DefaultView;
        pagedDS.AllowPaging = true;
        pagedDS.PageSize = 6;
        pagedDS.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

        dlPaging.DataSource = pagedDS;
        dlPaging.DataBind();

        // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
        cmdPrev.Enabled = !pagedDS.IsFirstPage;
        cmdNext.Enabled = !pagedDS.IsLastPage;
    }

   protected void cmdPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set viewstate variable to the previous page
        CurrentPage -= 1;
            PagedDataSource pagedDS = new PagedDataSource();
            pagedDS.DataSource = ((DataTable)Cache["DataTable-cach"]).DefaultView;// cacheItem.DefaultView;
            pagedDS.AllowPaging = true;
            pagedDS.PageSize = 6;
            pagedDS.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
            dlPaging.DataSource = pagedDS;
            dlPaging.DataBind();
            lblCurrentPage.Text = pagedDS.PageCount.ToString() + " صفحه    " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " از ";
            // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
            cmdPrev.Enabled = !pagedDS.IsFirstPage;
            cmdNext.Enabled = !pagedDS.IsLastPage;

    }
     public int CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            // look for current page in ViewState
            object o = this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
            if (o == null)
                return 0; // default page index of 0
            else
                return (int)o;
        }

        set
        {
            this.ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you friends
I edit html file

```
 <ContentTemplate>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  Sys.Application.add_load(BindEvents);
               </script>
               .
               .
               .
```

and edit my jquery file

```
function BindEvents() {
//my jquery codes
}
```

Be Happy

Answer (score 0):

When you go to next page of data list the onclick event  gets unbinded as update panel refresh the content inside div. So onclick event must be added again to get the expected result.
Try the following in cs page below your datalist bind code.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(id of update panel, 
                    typeof(UpdatePanel), "string", 
                    "$(function () {$('.prod_details_sell a img').click(function () {
                   //some code is here
                   });)", true);
```

Comment: thank  you,my jquery code in too long and with your way i had to write long jquery code on cs file

Comment: thank  you,my jquery code in too long and with your way i had to write long jquery code on cs file
also i test your code but not work!!

Comment: just write  a function and call that after dom is ready.You don't have to  write the long code twice. Can you show little bit of the cs code?How paging is implemented?

Comment: if you need any else please tell me.thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this:

```
$(".prod_details_sell a img").click(function () {
        //some code is here
});
```

with this:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(initJavaScripts);
function initJavaScripts() {
    $(".prod_details_sell a img").click(function () {
        //some code is here
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.i replace it on jquery file and jquery not work(on the first page and other). then According to pmtamal response,Sys.Application.add_load(initJavaScripts) write on cs file but gut syntax error.